# open fd leaks, while number of goroutines stay the same

Tags: multithreading, go, metrics, file-descriptor, goroutine

I have pretty simple application on go 1.8 that uses [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) 
During load test I see that quantity of open fd's grows from 9 to 200. I am pretty sure this is tcp sockets from client. How ever quantity of go-routines that is running stay the same: 14.

`process_open_fds 200`
`go_goroutines 14`

Latency also grows.

What can be wrong here? Where should I dig? For me it seems that the problem occurred before touching my code.

Comment: You server might not close sockets that were opened for keep-alive requests. You can set e.g. [IdleTimeout](https://godoc.org/net/http#Server.IdleTimeout) (and other timeouts) to close them after a specified time. There is [an example](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#custom-http-configuration) on how to use a custom server configuration in the readme of gin. Also see [this blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/#httplistenandserveisdoingitwrong)

Comment: Clients keeping open connections is expected in HTTP. Are the 200 connections causing a problem? We need a [mre] of some sort in order to any idea what is going on.